# Windows file found by cmd.exe but not PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, cmd.exe, path

On the same system, `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` yield
different results for listing a file both through its absolute
path and relative to $PWD:

[image: ENOENT]

CMD sees it, PowerShell doesn’t. The binary doesn’t seem to
have a “hidden” bit anywhere AFAICS.

I determined the path through the Windows search in Explorer.

What is happening here?

Comment: A PowerShell prompt can be run several different user contexts.  How are you launching the PowerShell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the 32-bit version of PowerShell on a 64-bit system. So the [WoW64 redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) applies to it – when a 32-bit program tries to access `C:\Windows\System32`, it is redirected to a different directory (`SysWoW64`) so that it finds 32-bit system files instead of 64-bit ones.

Be sure to launch PowerShell using the shortcut *without* "(x86)" in its name.

Comment: That was it thanks. Though the x86 context PS fails to locate the binary in SysWOW64 too …

Answer (score -1):

Removing this feature “**Windows PowerShell 2.0**” from “**Turn Windows Feature on or off**” worked for me.

[image: Removing PowerShell from Windows Features]